# how to connect Focusrite Scarlett 2i2 TO 24 channel Alto mixer

Tags: logic-pro, mixer

I need help on how to connect Focusrite Scarlett 2i2 TO 24 channel Alto Professional Live2404  mixer and record a live concert of 5 mics, drum, 2 keyboards, a lead guitar and bass guitar on Logic Pro X?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, what you are basically wanting to do is connect the mixer to the interface and not the inverse. The scarlett 2i2 has two TRS input jacks inside the XLR input jacks (through the hole between the XLR jacks).

Now, just plug in the instruments into the input channels of the mixer, adjust the parameters, check your settings using a pair of HD headphones and then, using two 6.1mm connecting wires, connect the two (L - R) output channels of the mixer to the respective (L - R) TRS(1/4") input channels of the audiobox usb. The TRS output jacks of the mixer are on the back panel of the Live 2404. The two jacks are placed vertically with respect to each other with a label saying `OUTPUT` above them.
Finally, connect the USB from the interface to your computer, manage your settings and record.

Answer (score 1):

From the start, this will suffer in sound quality and you will have almost no capability to work on separate tracks after recording. Unless you record each part separately on a different track. But here goes...
Go to the store and buy a TRS to XLR cable, then plug the XLR end into the master out (right/left) of the mixer and plug the TRS end into the 2i2. However, I would actually just consider investing in an 18i, then you could mix each channel separately into an independent recorded track and ultimately produce a much better recording.

Comment: Thanks for your help Blusician, but i couldn't figure out what 18i is please and just to be more specific, i have 2 active PA speakers plugged in at the back of my ALTO 2404 mixer which serves as output to the Audience. share more light on your explanation please.  thanks

Comment: I was referring to the Focusrite 18i8 or 18i20, or anything else with many more inputs. The 2i2 will not be possible unless you have two different (preferably stereo) monitor channels out of the Alto. You might be able to make something work if you have a mini stereo aux out of the Alto that you can split into the TLS inputs of the 2i2. But this would really be getting down to duct tape and bubble gum kind of setup. In fact, you may even get a better recording from one of the many stereo micro recorders.

Comment: That makes a little more sense then.  I just purchased a Scarlett series interface and the way they are named is a little deceptive.  They suggest there are however many inputs and outputs but they're not referring to 1/4" and XLR, which is what most people purchasing an interface at that price point would be looking for.